# GWT - Get session during RPC Service invocation

Tags: java, google-app-engine, session, gwt, servlets

I try to get session information during the first invocation of my RPC Service.

```
public class MyServiceImpl extends RemoteServiceServlet implements
MyService {

    public MyServiceImpl() {
        HttpServletRequest req = getThreadLocalRequest();
        // req = null here
    }
}
```

Client side, I make a simple call :

```
MyServiceAsync service = GWT.create(MyService.class);
```

Is there a alternative solution to get the HttpServletRequest during the first RPC invocation ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `getThreadLocalRequest()` in the constructor of the servlet which is only called once on servlet initialisation. At that time the request is not yest available.

You need to override the `processCall(String)` method which is called on every RPC invocation.

```
public class MyServiceImpl extends RemoteServiceServlet implements MyService {

    @Override
    public String processCall( String payload ) {
        HttpServletRequest req = getThreadLocalRequest();
        HttpSession session = req.getSession();
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried your solution but the processCall method is not called. Do I use another invocation solution than GWT.create(...) ?

Comment: What do  you mean it's not called? You need to invoke some RPC method on the `service` variable. You must remember that `MyServiceImpl` code is run on the server and `GWT.create(..)` is run on the client so there is no session or anything like that. At that point only a Javascript proxy is created.